# Integrate Numerically and Analytically

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for some help to answer this question for a mock paper. I'm hoping to get answers for Task 5.2.5 and 5.2.6. If someone could answer with a worked example or point me in the right direction for a good worked example of a similar question so that I can work it out myself that would be great. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints for the numerical integration (I'll assume you have Excel or something like that):

- pick a step size, say 0.01 mm.  Open a spreadsheet and fill in the values from 1.00 mm to 3.50 mm in a column.  (Or from 0.001 to 0.0035 m in increments of 0.00001 m, if you want to stay in MKS units.)
- For each of those 251 distances, calculate the value of the function you're integrating.  You can "fill down" with a function.
- Multiply those values by the step size.  This gives you the area of the individual skinny rectangles that form the area.  (Exclude one of the ends.)  If you want to get closer, calculate the trapezoidal area instead.
- Add them all up.

A hint on the analytic integration:

- Replace all of the numbers with letters to reduce clutter.
- Calculate the integral, and re-substitute in the values.

So your integral would be something like:

$$V = - \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \frac{C}{r}dr.$$

That integral is a little easier on the eyes.  Figure out what $r_1, r_2, C$ are, and re-substitute in after you integrate.